# Bluetooth and GPS on Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, nexus-4, gps

Is there anybody who has no problems using Bluetooth or GPS on Nexus 4 with ubuntu touch?

If so, can you please tell me which channel you are using or which settings you are using?

I'm asking to find out if I have a Hardware problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just flashed `--channel=ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/ubuntu` and my bluetooth is working again.

Comment: you said 'again'. Does this mean it had not been working in the past?

Answer (score 0):

The BQ channel has the nonfree drivers for working GPS, but I don't have a issue with Bluetooth on the normal channel.

Comment: So BQ channel would work for Nexus devices? I thought it would just work with BQ devices. I'm going to try it out.

Comment: ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/bq-aquaris.en

Answer (score 0):

Just flashed `--channel=ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu --bootstrap` on my nexus 4, and the GPS is working fine if the wireless is OFF. Bluetooth doesn't seem to work, though.

Answer (score 0):

I for one flashed the latest OTA-9 on the Nexus 4 and both Bluetooth and Wifi work together as I tested streaming Youtube via Bluetooth while connected to Wifi.
So the best thing to do is try and flash the device again.